# Android NDK : How to get screen resolution in native binary?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a native binary for `armeabi-v7a` running on an Android phone that needs to get the current resolution of the screen.

I've tried reading the framebuffer resolution from `/dev/graphics/fb0` but it gives me an incorrect value (640 X 400).

Most of the solutions discussed online involve using `Java`, `ANativeWindow` or `ANativeWindow_Buffer`, none of which are applicable to my scenario.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who stumbles across this, I eventually ended up processing the output of the below command.

```
su -c dumpsys display | grep mBaseDisplayInfo
```